# Error running node in cloud9 IDE?

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide, cloud9

First i got the following  error and i couldn't figure yet what is this about:
[image: what is wrong with DOCTYPE?]
any idea?

Comment: better post code/error messages as text rather than screenshot

Comment: It was really necessary to down-vote the question ? As you can see in the image there is far to many errors to be able to write all of them.

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted it

Comment: my bad then... can you link the rules regarding to the images because its second time i got commented on this and both times was error on the terminal

Comment: A thread about posting code as screenshot: 
 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: The reason why text code/error message is preferred rather than a screenshot is because people can hardly edit/search the code or error message if you provide it as a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to open an HTML file with Node.js.

Node.js is supposed to run JavaScript code (typically stored in .js files) and it cannot parse your HTML file, which is why you're getting these errors.

You could try executing the files called *app.js* or *server.js* with the following commands:

```
node app.js
```

or

```
node server.js
```

Also, it seems your project (or whatever it is you're working on) has a README.md file which could help to clarify where you're supposed to start.

Comment: Oh very good! I forgot to change it for app.js! thanks very much for your answer!